# How to avoid a Netbeans error with an HTML block nested in PHP if statement

Tags: php, html, netbeans

Consider the following example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Row One</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    if ($rowtwo)
    {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>Row Two</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

If `$rowtwo` is true, the second row is output, otherwise it is skipped.

The code works as desired, however I am evaluating Netbeans (7 beta) as a PHP IDE (instead of just using a text editor). Netbeans flags the code with an error:

> Misplaced non-space characters insided
>   [sic] a table.

Should I consider an alternate way of writing this code, or is Netbeans incapable of understanding this flow control wrapper for HTML output?

**Edit**

The example does not show the indentation I originally used, however various methods of indentation do not affect Netbeans in flagging it as an error.

Removing whitespace prior to the `<?php` and `?>` tags as well as using `endif;` instead of curly braces both result in the same functionality, but are still flagged.

I think this is a problem and/or weak point with Netbeans' code parsing.

Comment: code seems perfect to me. i do it all the time.

Comment: Consider using the shorthand syntax for control structures: `<? if(...): ?><html><? endif ?>`, this won't clutter your document with curly brackets.

Comment: @xrstf: It's called alternative, not shorthand. (But you don't have to take the words of a nitpick for it :)

Comment: I have hundreds of such a files and Netbeans says not a word about it. What is extension of this file?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: The extension is .php. I'm trying various combinations of white-space/no white-space to see if it's something to do with Netbeans not detecting the php section.

Comment: @JYelton I'd suggest you to edit the title too, to something "Howe to get rid of Netbeans senseless error message"

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Edited per your suggestion -- I guess that is the true focus of the question. Originally Netbeans' flagging it as an error caused me to think a construct I've used for years was somehow wrong.

Comment: Netbeans flags some "errors" for me, assignment in the condition for example. I just don't care

Comment: I guess I am used to the ability to customize and relative accuracy of Resharper in Visual Studio as it applies to C#. I'm looking at development environments for small PHP projects that offer some level of error checking and resource management that is somewhat similar. Maybe it's time to check out Eclipse...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the advantages of PHP is being able to insert PHP code fragments right in your HTML. Your code above is fine. Alternatively, you can do it like this, but both are exactly the same.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Row One</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    if($rowtwo) {
      echo "<tr>\n";
      echo "\t\t<td>Row Two</td>\n";
      echo "\t</tr>\n";
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Not sure why your answer was voted down just for showing an alternative way of doing the exact same thing. It's not optimized, but it does the same thing.

Comment: The only thing wrong with your code is a missing closing curly brace. +1 because this is the only answer that successfully avoids the Netbeans error. While not ideal, it shows an understanding that Netbeans is not correctly identifying the inline PHP. By moving it into PHP output, the HTML tags are effectively taken out of Netbeans' error-checking scope and it stops complaining.

Comment: @JYelton Thanks for noticing the missing bracket. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty typical syntax for presentational views in PHP and other similar languages. It's not elegant, and it's likely to confuse IDEs, but it's not generally considered bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is valid php. Netbeans may be trying to validate it as HTML, but I don't know much about netbeans.

A couple suggestions:

- don't put white-space before php opening tags (`<?php`) it makes it easier to scan a file and see where the php blocks are located
- use the `if (...): endif;` blocks for HTML content:

I.E.:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Row One</td>
  </tr>
<?php if ($rowtwo): ?>
  <tr>
    <td>Row Two</td>
  </tr>
<?php endif; ?>
</table>
```

it helps so you can see where the if statement ends, rather than trying to determine which closing bracket is which. you can also do this for [other control structures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

Edit for more details:

I break out of my html indentation with my php indentation. A next level block would look something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Row One</td>
  </tr>
<?php if ($rowtwo): ?>
  <tr>
    <td>Row Two</td>
  </tr>
<?php   if ($condition): ?>
  <tr>
    <td>More Content</td>
  </tr>
<?php   endif; ?>
  <tr>
    <td>Even more content</td>
  </tr>
<?php endif; ?>
</table>
```

I should also mention that my `body` element is indented one level, so I rarely ever have html that is flush against my php tags. Often it's more like:

```
    <table>
<?php if ($condition): ?>
      <tr><td></td></tr>
<?php endif; ?>
    </table>
```

Which helps to make the PHP stand out.

Comment: Honestly, I find this less readable.  First, why does the PHP block start at another block level than the HTML (I know why you did it, but it's not intuitive and can be hard to follow)?  What happens if you add another level?  Not to mention that I don't think that the alternative syntax is nearly as intuitive as the `{}` syntax.  I personally don't like to see it, but it's up to preference (it's not right or wrong)...

Comment: Honestly, I think that's worse (the edited indentation bit).  I'd honestly recommend giving [Code Complete 2](http://www.amazon.com/Code-Complete-Practical-Handbook-Construction/dp/0735619670) a read to better understand why...  After all, it makes it next to impossible to understand without trying to figure out what's going on.  As far as making the PHP stand out, I think that's less important than you make it out to be (I think being able to figure out what it does with little effort is far more important)

Comment: @ircmaxell I've updated my answer with some more examples for indentation. The important part is that you format your code consistently. If you're working with someone else it can be helpful to decide on some simple styling rules so that you're not constantly getting a headache from trying to read the other person's code.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Alternate indenting and flow control syntax changes do not affect the output nor Netbeans' marking it as an error. While I agree that style considerations are important for various reasons, it is not the purpose nor focus of my question. I updated the question with this information.

Comment: Exactly How I do it! I am just using short tags to make it more concise

Comment: @JYelton if you add whitespace before/after the php tags it changes the output; be very careful with trailing newline chars after a php-close tag.

Comment: YMMV depending on what you're used to, but I think the argument that `endif` is easier to spot in a sea of markup than `}` is a credible one, and I also find that consistently using this syntax in templating/view situations gives me quick context (that this is a conditional part of the presentation rather than control flow for the underlying logic).

Answer (score 0):

It's almost acceptable by my standards (What I look for in other people's code).  The only change I would make is to indent properly so that it's easier to see at a glance what's happening (make your code more readable).  For example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Row One</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    if ($rowtwo) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td>Row Two</td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

That way, it's trivial to see where the if construct ends at a glance...

Comment: Honestly, I find this less readable. it makes not concise and clear operator, but fill featured spaghetti

Comment: @Col: To each their own.  But in my experience, this is more readable (since you can read it on both levels (PHP and HTML) just as easy as the other.  Sure, it's slightly harder to scan for PHP code, but you should be using a syntax highlighting editor, that shouldn't matter as much as being able to visually identify where the "levels" start and stop.  But to each their own I guess...

Answer (score 0):

It is not bad practice or wrong to a certain extent. 
However, a better practice is to separate your display logic from your business logic. Your IDE is probably assuming this, and therefore is confused with mixed code.

But again, nothing wrong with mixing html/php!